# react-scripts build works, but craco build fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-module-federation, craco

For my React App, I am trying to implement Module Federation using CRACO.

My dependencies in `package.json` are as below;

```
"dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5",
    "react": "~17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "~17.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "~6.3.0",
    "reactstrap": "~9.1.1",
    "windowed-observable": "~0.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "7.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "~5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "~10.4.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "~14.1.1",
    "cross-env": "~7.0.3",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "~3.0.3",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "7.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "~5.0.1",
    "sass": "~1.32.13",
    "typescript": "~4.7.4",
    "craco-module-federation": "1.1.0"
  },
```

My `craco.config.js` is as below;

```
const cracoModuleFederation = require('craco-module-federation');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: cracoModuleFederation,
    },
  ],
};
```

My `modulefederation.config.js` is as below;

```
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;

module.exports = {
    name: "transactionUi",
    exposes: {
        //"./MyComp": "./src/components/App.js",
    },
    filename: "remoteEntry.js",
    shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: deps["react"],
        },
        "react-dom": {
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
    },
};
```

If I run "`react-scripts build`", the build is successful.
But if I run `craco build`, I get the below error;

```
I:\UICode\mfe\my-ui\my-ui-web\node_modules\craco-module-federation\index.js:43                                                                                                              
        new webpack.container.ModuleFederationPlugin(                                                                                                                                                                                
                            ^                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ModuleFederationPlugin')                                                                                                                                                    
        at Object.overrideWebpackConfig (I:\UICode\mfe\my-ui\my-ui-web\node_modules\craco-module-federation\index.js:43:31)                                                                     
        at overrideWebpack (I:\UICode\mfe\my-ui\my-ui-web\node_modules\@craco\craco\dist\lib\features\plugins.js:36:38)                                                                         
        at I:\UICode\mfe\my-ui\my-ui-web\node_modules\@craco\craco\dist\lib\features\plugins.js:53:29                                                                                           
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        at applyWebpackConfigPlugins (I:\UICode\mfe\my-ui\my-ui-web\node_modules\@craco\craco\dist\lib\features\plugins.js:52:29)                                                               
        at mergeWebpackConfig (I:\UICode\mfe\my-ui\my-ui-web\node_modules\@craco\craco\dist\lib\features\webpack\merge-webpack-config.js:119:70)                                                
        at overrideWebpackProd (I:\UICode\mfe\my-ui\my-ui-web\node_modules\@craco\craco\dist\lib\features\webpack\override.js:14:80)                                                            
        at I:\UICode\mfe\my-ui\my-ui-web\node_modules\@craco\craco\dist\scripts\build.js:20:40                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    Node.js v18.18.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The plugin [`craco-module-federation`](https://github.com/hasanayan/craco-module-federation/) doesn't seem to be compatible with [`craco`](https://github.com/dilanx/craco) v7. There is an existing [PR](https://github.com/hasanayan/craco-module-federation/pull/11) made some years ago to add support for it, but it was never merged. You probably need to implement the plugin yourself rather than using this library.

You should also know that CRA (and so `react-scripts`) [is no longer maintained](https://github.com/reactjs/react.dev/pull/5487#issuecomment-1409720741). You may want to switch to a custom webpack config or migrate to another bundler in the future.